# Using the OpenFileDialouge selection in a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to use an OpenFileDialouge control to select a folder, so that it can select a file and output it into my code below:

```
    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("test.exe", <openfiledialouge-output-here> );
    }
```

So  would contain the selected file

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: button18? Do future you / future developer a favor and give your buttons meaningful names. They will travel back in time to thank you.

Comment: @asawyer: "button18" might be a meaningful name, if the text of the button is "18" ;)  It also lets you know that you probably have too many buttons on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) to select folder, not OpenFileDialog.

Comment: He is trying to select a file, not a folder

Comment: `I am trying to use an OpenFileDialouge control to select a folder` FOLDER! read it again.

Comment: The original question indicated selecting a file after the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is the MSDN docs, better imo.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx